# My Java code does not run, how can I debug it?

Tags: java, debugging

```
package FinaExamlOOP;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Arithmaticx1 {
    private static int average;
    public static void main(String [] args ) throws FileNotFoundException {
        int number1;
        int number2;
        int number3;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print( "Number 1? " );
        System.out.print( "Number 2? " );
        System.out.print( "Number 3? " );

        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("output.txt");

        number1 = in.nextInt();
        number2 = in.nextInt();
        number3 = in.nextInt();

        int average = ((number1 + number2 + number3) / 3);

        System.out.print( number1 + ", " + number2 + " & " + number3 );
        System.out.println( " averages to " + average );

        out.println(number1 + ", " + number2 + " & " + number3 );
        out.println( " averages to " + average );

        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

I'm using NetBeans IDE 8.0.2 and whenever I click 'run' for this code, it keeps loading and not running the outcome. How can I fix this?

Comment: The application waits for input entered in a console (see `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)`). So maybe you don't see any output because the application is watiting for your input?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: The best way to debug is through the debugger in you IDE. Another way is to put copious System.out.println() statements into your code, which will let you know what is happening in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try writing things into the console like for the numbers, since you didn't stagger the questions and the answers, you have to write all the numbers at once. If you write in 3 numbers, the Scanner will pick them up and print it out for you. Also, if you want to improve upon your code, try this:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print( "Number 1? " );
    in.nextInt();
    System.out.print( "Number 2? " );
    in.nextInt();
    System.out.print( "Number 3? " );
    in.nextInt();
```

This gets the values right after you ask for the numbers, so people have time to answer.